# Drawing the integration region of a triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Good afternoon everyone!

I have a lot of difficulties in changing the variables of integration in a triple integral, because I usually can't make a drawing of the integrating region.

I have a calculus exam tomorrow, and I would like to know if you have any suggestions in how I could manually draw the integrating region of a triple integral or of how to change the variables of integration without making any drawings (because calculators aren't allowed in the exam).

One example of such a problem would be the following integral:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{x^2+y^2-1}^{2-x} dz dy dx$$

For example, to change it to:

$$\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}\int_{e}^{f} dy dx dz$$

Comment: Don't worry about drawing the region for a triple integral. Here, cylindrical coordinates seems best.

Comment: I wish I could. Unlucky, I have a question in my exam that specifically asks to do so...
Still, how would I change it to cylindrical coordinates?